# Linear regression with ongoing data, in R

Tags: r, loops, regression, lm

Modell

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
```

about 1000 rows

What Iwant to do is to do an prediction "step-by-step"

Using Row 0:20 to predict y of 21:30 and then using 11:30 to predict y of 31:40 and so on.

Comment: What do you mean by the "with the last 20 rows" in  "predict the next 10 results with the last 20 rows"? Also, you should add the code that you tried, and some data for us to work with (the first rows from your df, try using the `dput` function)

Comment: You could consider using a random 2/3th split of your dataset in a training and validation dataset. Then train one linear model on the training dataset and validate it on your validation dataset. Depending on your dataset and ideas it might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `predict` function:

```
mod = lm(y ~ ., data=df[1:990,])
pred = predict(mod, newdata=df[991:1000,2:4])
```

Edit: to change the range of training data in a loop:

```
index = seq(10,990,10)
pred = matrix(nrow=10, ncol=length(index)) 

for(i in index){
  mod = lm(y ~ ., data=df[1:i,])
  pred[,i/10] = predict(mod, newdata=df[(i+1):(i+10),2:4])
  MSE[i/10] = sum((df$y[(i+1):(i+10)]-pred[,i/10])^2)}

mean(MSE)
```

Comment: I did use the lm function before and the results where pretty bad, what i want to try is to do the regression "step-bystep" in a loop whre i use 0:20 for the prediction of 20:30 and then 10:30 for 30:40 and so on, but thank you very much for the fast answer

Comment: Check if it works now. If you can, add some data so i can test it before answering it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: I had the indexes wrong, just edited again. Also added the MSE calculation inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
# set up mock data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(1000),
                 x1 = rnorm(1000),
                 x2 = rnorm(1000),
                 x3 = rnorm(1000))

# for loop
prd <- list()

for(i in 1:970){
 
 # training data
 trn <- df[i:(i+20), ]

 # test data
 tst <- df[(i+21):(i+30), ]
 
 # lm model 
 mdl <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, trn)

 # append a list of data.frame with both predicted and actual values
 # for later confrontation
 prd[[i]] <- data.frame(prd = predict(mdl, tst[-1]),
                        act = tst[[1]])
 
}

# your list
prd
```

---

You can also try something fancier with the package `slider`:

```
# define here your model and how you wanna handle the preditions
sliding_lm <- function(..., frm, n_trn, n_tst){

 df <- data.frame(...)
 trn <- df[1:n_trn, ]
 tst <- df[n_trn+1:n_tst, ]
 
 mdl <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, trn)
 data.frame(prd = predict(mdl, tst[-1]),
            act = tst[[1]])
 
}

n_trn <- 20 # number of training obs
n_tst <- 10 # number of test obs
frm <- y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 # formula of your model

prd <- slider::pslide(df, sliding_lm, 
                      frm = frm,
                      n_trn = n_trn,
                      n_tst = n_tst,
                      .after = n_trn + n_tst, 
                      .complete = TRUE)
```

Note that the last 30 entries in the list are NULL, because you look only at complete windows [30 observations with training and test]